# app crashing in doing slide menu in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, slide

I am doing slide menu like Facebook in iOS a simple app I where doing step by step process from tutorial which available in this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path
. I am only doing right panel slide when I click button it moving slide happening but when I call my main view again it is happening but app getting crash could any one help me to get out from this problem

```
#define RIGHT_PANEL 2
#define CENTRAL_TAG 1
#define SLIDE_TIMING .25
#define PANEL_WIDTH 60
@interface MainViewController ()<CenterViewControllerDelegate>



@property(nonatomic,strong)CentralViewController *centralView;
@property(nonatomic,strong)RightViewController *RightView;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL showingRightPanel;

-(UIView*)getright;
-(UIView*)resetmainView;
@end



@implementation MainViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.centralView = [[CentralViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CentralViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.centralView.view.tag = CENTRAL_TAG;

    self.centralView.delegate=self;


    [self.view addSubview:self.centralView.view];
    [self addChildViewController:_centralView];

    [_centralView didMoveToParentViewController:self];




}
-(UIView*)getright
{

if(_RightView==Nil)
    {
        self.RightView=[[RightViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RightViewController" bundle:Nil];

        self.RightView.view.tag=RIGHT_PANEL;
        self.RightView.delegate=self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.RightView.view];
        [self addChildViewController:self.RightView];
        [_RightView didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        _RightView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    }
    self.showingRightPanel=YES;
    UIView *view=self.RightView.view;
    return view;
}

-(void)MovetoOriginal
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_TIMING delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         _centralView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {

                             [self resetmainView];
                         }
                     }];}

-(void)rightpanelmove
{
    UIView *child=[self getright];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:child];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_TIMING delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         _centralView.view.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width + PANEL_WIDTH, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {

                             _centralView.rightbutton.tag = 1;
                         }
                     }];

}


-(UIView*)resetmainView
{
    if(_RightView!=Nil)
    {
        [self.RightView.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.RightView=Nil;
        _centralView.rightbutton.tag=0;
        self.showingRightPanel=NO;
    }
```

This is my main control code where am calling the event

And this one is button action code

```
- (IBAction)btnright:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = sender;
    switch (button.tag) {
        case 0: {
            [_delegate rightpanelmove];
            break;
        }

        case 1: {

             [_delegate MovetoOriginal];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }}
```

Comment: print your crash log here :)

Comment: crashing means it showing thread error in line [self resetmainView] and and its function

Comment: Please share your error message with us. The full message that comes up on the console. Edit your question for that to make it readable.

Comment: And if you got a problem in resetmainView, then please share the full code of that method with us, not just the beginning. You missed at least the return statement.

Comment: No i showed full check out the tutorial i where doing from that tutorial only

Comment: @HermannKlecker You are absolutely correct i missed to return main view while calling resetmainview thanks for your time now it is works

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView*)resetmainView
{
    if(_RightView!=Nil)
    {
        [self.RightView.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.RightView=Nil;
        _centralView.rightbutton.tag=0;
        self.showingRightPanel=NO;
    }

    UIView *view=self.centralView.view;
    return view;

}
```

This what i missed now it is working!!!!

Comment: Strange. Didn't the compiler warn about not returning anything from a method with a return value?

Comment: @HermannKlecker see my previous comments i already suggested your answer as you said i didn't return my view in that code. See above now am returning the view so got output man!